# How to quarantine a specific subversion revision?

Tags: svn

I have a revision that has been committed to SVN trunk which I would like to roll back.  However, I would like to retain the changes in some fashion such as a branch or even a patch file.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reverse-merge (I think that was the term), commit and that's all.

For the "reverse-merge" part - TSVN has this cool feature called "Revert to this revision" (and "Revert changes from this revision"), accessible through the Log dialogue.

The main purpose of a VCS is to keep history of your changes. You could always go back to this particular revision by using "Update to revision..." or by using the aforementioned "shortcuts".

Comment: And would I reinstate the changes at a later date?

Comment: You can restore the changes by reverting the previous revert.

Comment: Odd - I don't see the "Revert to this revision" option.  Is there a security setting that could hide this option from me?

Comment: @myself, I was going in through the Repo Browser, which is why the option was not available.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a particular revision when you do a copy (ie. branch).

Something like:

```
svn copy -rsome_revision trunk branches/interesting_branch
```

So roll back your changes in your trunk and then do your branch, specifying the revision before you commited your rollback (merge).

You can also capture the differences as a patch file, if that's what you really want to do, by redirecting the output of an `svn diff` to a text file.
But that's usually not necessary, as the subversion merge commands give you this flexibility already.